# grep column from different files according to the first column value

Tags: bash, grep

I need help in extracting one column of numbers from many different files and display it in an output file.

Specifically, I want to extract the second column (`$2`) from each file, `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` etc., according the the value of the first column, then place all extracted columns in a one file, `out.txt`.

The problem is that the first column has different intervals in each file:

`file`:

```
0.50 x1
1.25 x2
1.50 x3
1.75 x4
2.00 x5
```

`file2`:

```
0.25 y1
0.50 y2
1.00 y3
1.25 y4
2.00 y5
```

Desired output:

```
0.25    y1
0.50 x1 y2
1.00    y3
1.25 x2 y4
1.50 x3
1.75 x4
2.00 x5 y5
```

Comment: [edit] your question showing some representative input, desired output and what you tried so far. See [ask] also for a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is important format of the number, not value. There is number, dot and one or more numbers, which you should write in regex: \d\.\d+

If your file has more columns the best way how to extract exact column is use awk first.
This way you may set column number:

```
$ var=3
$ ls -l | awk '{print $'$var'}'
```

---

I dont think that it is a task for bash (I dont say that it is not possible), so I wrote my solution in python:

```
import re, sys

num = {}
files = ['file1', 'file2']

for file in files:
    f = open(file,'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        cont = re.match(r"(\d+\.\d+)\s(.*)", line)
        if cont != None:
            if float(cont.group(1)) not in num:
                num[float(cont.group(1))] = []
            num[float(cont.group(1))].append(cont.group(2))
    f.close()

for key in num:
    sys.stdout.write(str(key)+' ')
    print num[key]
```

---

file1:

```
0.5 x1
0.8 x2
0.3 x3
```

file2:

```
1.3 y1
0.5 y2
0.0 y3
```

output:

```
0.5 ['x1', 'y2']
0.0 ['y3']
1.3 ['y1']
0.3 ['x3']
0.8 ['x2']
```

Comment: what I need is to extract all values of column no 2 from all files corresponding to each value if column 1, for example the value 0.25 from column 1 has corresponding values in column 2 in  files 1,5,6 but it deosnot have corresponding values in some other files and so on, each file has only two columns

Comment: It looks I dont understand :D Try to give me an example of input and corresponding output.

Comment: Dear  Andrew I trying to add a photo with format of two files but I can't give me your email to send the photo or files two have a look

Comment: 1) you may add photos here - edit your question

2) give me basic example

Comment: I will try it even without example.
Store the value from first column of file1:

`$ val=$(cat file1 | awk '{print $1}' | grep -Po '\d')`

Then find the number in file2, file3 and file4:

`$ for i in 2 3 4 ; do;  awk '{print $2}' file$i | grep -Po $val; done`

Comment: please see the photo in the following link    
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtp0l03uoj4135t/Screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: my reputation is not enough for neither chat or posting image

Comment: please modify the script to grep all number in column 1 because it grep only to less 10

Comment: I did - instead \d there must be \d+

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `gawk` and 2-d array in it as:

```
gawk 'FNR==NR{a[$1][0]=$2;a[$1][1]=1;next} {print $0,a[$1][0]; a[$1][1]=0;} END{for(i in a){if (a[i][1] == 1) print i,a[i][0];}}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
0.50 x1 y2
1.25 x2 y4
1.50 x3 
1.75 x4 
2.00 x5 y5
1.00 y3
0.25 y1
```