# How do I organize new files according to the first column values of the original files?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk

Lets say I have 3 files: `File-A`, `File-B`, `File-C`; where each file has two columns of data (space delineated) but an unknown (and variable) number of rows.

**Input**

```
File-A:
1 dE
1 dF         
2 dF
2 dH         

File-B:    
1 dI         
3 dJ
3 dK         

File-C:
2 dF
3 dH
3 dJ
3 dK
4 dL
```

How do I efficiently sort that data so I create new files for each value in the first column (i.e., `File-1`, `File-2`, `File-3`, `File-4`) that keeps track of both their 2nd column partner data and the original file name?

**Desired Output**

```
File-1:      
A dE
A dF
B dI

File-2:    
A dF
A dH         
C dF         

File-3:
B dJ
B dK
C dH
C dJ
C dK

File4:
C dL
```

In actuality, I have several hundred thousand original files, each with a few hundred lines of data (but the total number of both original files and new files are known). What would be the most time efficient way to achieve this type of sorting?

Would a Bash script be the fastest method vs. a program like Fortran? I am just learning sed and awk – would something like that work best?

If a similar question has been asked before a link would be appreciated.  The [closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855895/grep-column-from-diffrent-files-according-to-the-first-colunn-value) I have found thus far seems to suggest awk might be a way to go.

Comment: "Would a bash script be the fastest method vs. [...]": no :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (probably very slow) Bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for suffix in "${@##*-}"; do    # Get suffix from each file name
    while read -r col1 col2; do # Read two columns

        # Assemble output line and write to proper file
        printf "%s %s\n" "$suffix" "$col2" >> "File-$col1"
    done < "File-$suffix"
done
```

Bash loops are slow, and many redirections are slow, but I can't think of another way of doing this because every input line potentially goes to another output file.

Something potentially faster in awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# For each new file, get the file name suffix
FNR == 1 {
    split(FILENAME, arr, "-")
    suffix = arr[2]
}

# On each line, create the output file name, then print to that file
{
    ofname = "File-" $1
    print suffix, $2  > ofname
}
```

Both are called from the command line with `./scriptname File-*`.

**Limit number of open file handles**

There are limits to how many file handles can be open at the same time: from your operating system, and from awk. Gawk does some trickery<sup>1</sup> to get around that, but it might still be faster (and definitely more portable) to avoid having too many open file handles.

A remedy would be, for example, to keep track of the open file handles per input file, then close them before processing the next file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# For each new file, get the file name suffix
FNR == 1 {
    # Close open files
    for (fname in openfiles)
        close(openfiles[fname])
    split(FILENAME, arr, "-")
    suffix = arr[2]
}

# On each line, create the output file name, then print to that file
{
    ofname = "File-" $1
    openfiles[ofname] = 1   # Keep track of open files
    print suffix, $2  > ofname
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html):

> If you use more files than the system allows you to have open, `gawk` attempts to multiplex the available open files among your data files. `gawk`’s ability to do this depends upon the facilities of your operating system, so it may not always work.
>
> It is therefore both good practice and good portability advice to always use `close()` on your files when you are done with them. In fact, if you are using a lot of pipes, it is essential that you close commands when done.

Comment: The awk script is the right approach and will be orders of magnitude faster than the shell loops but you should mention that if it's not gawk then it'll need to close() the files as it goes or end up with too many open simultaneously.